# Limitations of using WebBrowser control to create WPF apps

Tags: wpf

I've recently stumbled across `WebBrowser WPF control`. I am interested if there are any limitations when building user interfaces with HTML+CSS+JS and embedding them in `WebBrowser`.

So far I've successfully

- intercepted HTML click events and handled them in C# using
  `[ComVisible(true)]` class attribute
- called JS script from C# using `InvokeScript` method.

  [InvokeScript also supports sending objects to the HTML/JS via parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.invokescript?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_WebBrowser_InvokeScript_System_String_#System_Windows_Controls_WebBrowser_InvokeScript_System_String_System_Object___)  which faciliates two way communication.

Is there any reason for not using `WebBrowser` to create simple apps? I am intersted in parts that absolutely need to be handled with some WPF code and cannot be bridged using `WebBrowser`.

Comment: The possible limitations depend on your app requirements. Under the hood `WebBrowser` uses IE engine, you have to enable an emulation feature for the latest installed IE version, and use `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"` meta tag on your web page, per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do) Also, you'll probably face with a COM interop at lot, in case of writing something more complicated, than MSDN samples

Comment: If you want to design your UI with `HTML+CSS+JS ` why not using `Electron` instead?

Comment: Thanks. I only need simple UI functionality. Electron unfortunately comes with 140 MB of baggage.

Comment: 140 MB rounded is 0 GB. That's not a real argument, WPF needs the .net framework.

Comment: .net framework comes preinstalled on windows.  I only need simple UI functionality. 140MB (or 70 compressed) for a to-do-list app is an overkill I find hard to explain to the end user

Comment: If this is something you're going to write then why isn't it all wpf and no webbrowser? Building a web page to interact with indirectly in a rather clunky manner doesn't seem like an obvious plan to me. Even if you're totally new to wpf, simple ui doesn't sound too hard.