# Limitations of using WebBrowser control to create WPF apps

Tags: wpf

I've recently stumbled across `WebBrowser WPF control`. I am interested if there are any limitations when building user interfaces with HTML+CSS+JS and embedding them in `WebBrowser`.

So far I've successfully

- intercepted HTML click events and handled them in C# using
  `[ComVisible(true)]` class attribute
- called JS script from C# using `InvokeScript` method.

  [InvokeScript also supports sending objects to the HTML/JS via parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.invokescript?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_WebBrowser_InvokeScript_System_String_#System_Windows_Controls_WebBrowser_InvokeScript_System_String_System_Object___)  which faciliates two way communication.

Is there any reason for not using using `WebBrowser` to create simple apps? I am intersted in parts that absolutely need to be handled with some WPF code and cannot be bridged using `WebBrowser`.

Comment: This question is off topic here, as it's about programming.

Comment: You already have the same question [Limitations of using WebBrowser control to create WPF apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59589712/limitations-of-using-webbrowser-control-to-create-wpf-apps)